# Trying to create bootable Windows10 USB drive with woeUSB. Seems uefi-ntfs.img is too big?

Tags: usb, windows-10, woeusb

Trying to burn a USB bootable with Win10 from linux. Wasted a whole evening by now. :-(

Installed woeUSB and read the tutorials. Tried various things, even switched from USB drive. Did not format it at 1st then NTFS. It seems uefi-ntfs is larger than 512kB.

Here's the 'curse' and result from CLI:

```
...
sudo woeusb -d /home/xxx/Downloads/Win10_21H1_EnglishInternational_x64.iso /dev/sdc --tgt-fs NTFS --no-color
WoeUSB v3.3.1
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdc...
/dev/sdc: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (dos): 55 aa
/dev/sdc: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Ensure that /dev/sdc is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdc...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day.
--2021-10-26 00:13:33--  https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/raw/master/res/uefi/uefi-ntfs.img
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.121.3
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbatard/rufus/master/res/uefi/uefi-ntfs.img [following]
--2021-10-26 00:13:33--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbatard/rufus/master/res/uefi/uefi-ntfs.img
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.110.133, 185.199.111.133, 185.199.109.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.110.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1048576 (1,0M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/WoeUSB.CsW6q3.tempdir/uefi-ntfs.img’

uefi-ntfs.img       100%[===================>]   1,00M  --.-KB/s    in 0,1s    

2021-10-26 00:13:33 (8,75 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/WoeUSB.CsW6q3.tempdir/uefi-ntfs.img’ saved [1048576/1048576]

dd: writing to '/dev/sdc2': No space left on device
1025+0 records in
1024+0 records out
524288 bytes (524 kB, 512 KiB) copied, 0,589478 s, 889 kB/s
The command "dd if="${download_directory}/uefi-ntfs.img" of="${uefi_ntfs_partition}"" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1635200001_9737"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

...

I am at a loss, searching the net for solutions... I downloaded the latest W10 and that did not work either.... What am I missing?

Hope you can help

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The only OS you mention is off-topic windows - why are you asking here?    read your post too; lack of space is pretty clear to me*

Comment: **Woeusb** installs of Windows installer have seldom worked for me. **mkusb** works best for me for creating a Windows install disk while in Ubuntu, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#New_method_works_with_current_versions_of_Windows.   **Ventoy** also works for making a Windows USB installer, but I could only get it working for UEFI mode.

Comment: @guiverc I am trying to create a Windows10 bootable from within Ubuntu. I thought that is on topic.

Comment: There is no mention of Ubuntu, or release details in your question; you only mention linux. Linux support is found in SE *Unix & Linux* which includes EOL/ESM & *development* releases of Ubuntu - only supported releases of Ubuntu are on-topic here, where you don't even mention Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

[UEFI:NTFS](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs) developer here (I am not the person developing WoeUSB but I am the person publishing the `uefi-ntfs.img` image used by WoeUSB).

We recently increased the size of the `uefi-ntfs.img` image from 512 KB to 1 MB, so that we could include binaries that are signed for Secure Boot, but it seems the WoeUSB developers hardcoded the size of the target partition where the image should be written to 512 KB, hence your issue.

As with any Open Source project that has a **dedicated** issue tracker, you should report this issue to the [WoeUSB issue tracker](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/issues) so that they can update their code. Thanks.

Comment: That explains why woeusb is connecting github while running. I am always sceptic when a program contacts 'something' on the internet. I reported the 512kB --> 1MB issue with the developers of woeusb. I also read that putting your uefi-ntfs in their data, instead of getting it from github on the flow, is in their todo list. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

WoeUSB maintainer passing by, this bug is now fixed in [WoeUSB 5.1.3](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases/tag/v5.1.3).

Comment: Thanks for keeping `woeusb` up to date :-) When selecting `--target-filesystem NTFS`, the installation should continue without `wimtools`. I'm adding it to the 'wish-list' in order to make it more convenient to use `woeusb`.

Answer (score 2):

### Now we talk about the [github version of `woeusb`](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases/tag/v5.1.3)

The github version is at 5.1.3 and works in Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS (and 18.04.x LTS, probably all current versions of Ubuntu, but I have not tested them).

### PPA version of `woeusb` deprecated

Please be aware that the `woeusb` PPA version at `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` is deprecated (works in Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS but fails in 20.04.x LTS). Today (2021-11-07) it is at version 3.3.1 (dated 2020-02-13).

### Test

- From the [WoeUSB github](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases/tag/v5.1.3) I downloaded and tested `woeusb-5.1.3.bash` as well as the version in the tarball. they differ only in the line specifying the version. So I used the separate version with explicit version number.
- I used the command line

  ```
  sudo ./woeusb-5.1.3.bash --target-filesystem NTFS --device Windows11.iso /dev/sdx
  ```
- `wimlib-imagex` was not found, and `woeusb` quit. It can be installed from the repository universe with the command

  ```
  sudo apt install wimtools
  ```

  It is needed, when installing into a FAT32 file system in order to split the huge wim file, but when selecting NTFS, the installation should continue without wimtools. That way the WoeUSB bash shellscript will work without `wimtools` (but it wants an internet connection in order to get `uefi-ntfs.img`).
- The USB drive with Windows installer

  - created in 18.04.6 LTS and 20.04.3 LTS
  - boots both

    - in UEFI mode (also with secure boot) and
    - in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode).